# Как указать JAVA_HOME для Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

Прочитал в гайде, что Tomcat нужно указать JVM. Для этого нужно в файле `bin/catalina.sh` как-то прописать путь до папки, куда была установлена Java. Папку нашел, но не понимаю как это сделать. Что и куда там прописывать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172258/how-to-set-java-home-or-catalina-home-if-i-have-more-than-1-version-used-for-pro

Comment: это нужно для того,чтобы развернуть opencms на ос ubuntu(не совсем понимаю как стартануть деплой этой crm в томкете.

Comment: все,установил. там надо только переменные до jdk и catalina_home(путь до корневой папки томкета) указать, а потом закинуть инсталяху opencms в директорию webapps.